# Rows are overlapping in CSS Grid

Tags: reactjs, css, grid-layout, css-grid

My `.dailyChart-grid-numbers` should allow me to list numbers on the top most layer, and their borders should extend all the way down. Everything works, except `.dailyChart-box-top` insists on sharing the same row as `.dailyChart-grid-numbers`.

Here it is in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/z6y936r2mx

Here is just the CSS:

```
.dailyChart{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(24,1fr)
}
.dailyChart-box-middle{
    background-color: red;
    border-right: 2px solid #000000;
    grid-row: 3/4
}

.dailyChart-box-top{
    background-color: green;
    grid-row: 2/3;
}

.dailyChart-box-bottom{
    background-color: blue;
    grid-row: 4/5;
}

.dailyChart-grid-numbers{
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    grid-row: 1/5;
    align-items: start;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output? It would also help if you didn't have React mixed in, as that limits who will be able to help you.

Comment: Almost - If I change my .dailyChart-grid-numbers - grid-row:1/2

Then it shows the correct positions: https://imgur.com/a/dv6WtvB

Except now the grid does not extend all the way down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined any rows. That means that rows are implicitly created.

The height of implicit rows is governed by the `grid-auto-rows` property, whose default value is `auto`. And that's the problem – the `auto` value, which is relative to other items on the same track.

If you define a value, the problem seems to be resolved. Try something like this:

```
.dailyChart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25px; /* new */
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/100vxj7wr7

Comment: But I want the height of rows to be 'fit' to their content. Hardcoding a pixel value doesn't seem like a good solution.